# Obj C - Present view controllers one after another

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

It may be simple, but i'm scratching my head to find out the issue.

I'm presenting a `UINavigationController` and once it's dismissed I need to present another one which is a `UITabBarController`, when I do that I get below error

> Warning: Attempt to present < MyTabBarViewController: 0xXXXX > on <
>   ParentViewController: 0XXX> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

```
UINavigationController *nav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myWeb"];
MyWebViewController *webVC = (MyWebViewController *)nav.topViewController;
[self presentViewController:webVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I can see `MyWebViewController` is presented without any issue, once the previous one is dismissed, I try to present next one like below, I'm getting the above warning.

```
MyTabBarViewController *trController = [[MyTabBarViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:trController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to present MyTabBarViewController only when the MyWebViewController has finished dismissing,
try adding a delay like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    MyTabBarViewController *trController = [[MyTabBarViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:trController animated:NO completion:nil];
});
```

if this works, you will need to get rid of that (in case you want to keep your code clean) and call a delegate method inside `completion` telling the parent  that the MyTabBarViewController is ready to be presented.

Comment: Yeah, I'm presenting the second view controller on the call back from the first view controller dismiss function..

Comment: Oh, great...I can see that it's working when I add delay... Could you please explain on call a delegate method inside completion

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDL639kpNro this guy is the best. I really recommend you to take a look at https://www.raywenderlich.com/